# htaccess authentication by user and ip with an exception for a special file

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I want to do access-control for some files on an apache2-webserver (2.2.9(Debian)) depending on the the remote-ip and the a supplied username using a htaccess-file.

Rules:

1. All users from localhost have access to all files and should never be asked to authenticate themselves.
2. Users from a remote-host have to authenticate themselves via http-basic authentication. They also have access to all files apart from a single file, which should not be visible to them.

My htaccess-file posted below allows remote-users to login und forbids access to adm.php. Unfortunately the localhost user needs to enter a password. What do I need to change in order to let a local user access adm.php without a password dialog popping up?

```
AuthType Basic
Authname "Test-App"
AuthUserFile /etc/web_passwd
Require valid-user
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Deny from all
Satisfy Any

<Files adm.php>
   Order Deny,Allow
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
   Deny from all
   Satisfy all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_setenvif and then use the code below in your `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`:

```
<Files "adm.php">
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
   Satisfy all
</Files>

<FilesMatch "(?!^adm\.php)^.*$">
   AuthType Basic
   Authname "Test-App"
   AuthUserFile /etc/web_passwd
   Require valid-user

   Order      deny,allow
   Deny from  all
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
   Satisfy    any
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I tried your solution. The local user is now able to access adm.php without authentication. Unfortunately the remote-user can now access adm.php after entering credentials. I think the problem is the entry "Satisfy any" that allows the authenticated user from the remote host.

Comment: Above code will allow local users to browse any URL or a remote user to browse `/adm.php` **without** any authentication. A remote user trying to browse any URI other than `/adm.php` will have to go through authentication.

Comment: You are right thats exactly what the file does, but I want the remote user **not** to be able to access adm.php, but access the rest after he has entered his credentials

Comment: Ah I misinterpreted the requirements then. Let me rework the code to suite your ask.